# PHP design pattern factory input for products and quotes

Tags: php, design-patterns, factory-method

I'm working on figuring out the best way to design this so that it's well organized and it seems like the factory design pattern makes sense.

Updated:
**What I'm building:**
 - Pricing calculator 
 - There are 4 products each having their own specific pricing rules that vary from user input 
 - The person can choose between 1 product or all products

Should I have a Calculator class to determine product pricing or leave the calculations in each product type?

```
/*
 * Use Factory Pattern to build objects
 */

class ProductFactory {
    public static function createProduct($type) {
        switch ($type) {
            case 'solution1':
                return new Solution1Product();
                break;

            case 'solution2':
                return new Solution2Product();
                break;

            case 'solution3':
                return new Solution3Product();
                break;

            case 'solution4':
                return new Solution4Product();
                break;
        }

    }
}


/*
 * Abstract Product
 */

abstract class AbstractProduct {
    protected $price;
    protected $max_limit;
    protected $max_amount;

    abstract public function calculatePrice($dob, $gender, $amount);
}


/*
 * Solution 1 Product
 */
class Solution1Product extends AbstractProduct {
    protected $max_limit = 50000;

    function __contruct() {
        print "Test";
        return "Solution1";
    }

    function calculatePrice($dob, $gender, $amount) {
        $rate = 1.03;
        $price = 55;

        if ($amount >= $this->max_limit) {
            return "Max Limit Reached";
        }
        //@TODO go lookup price from tables


        $this->price = $rate * $price;
        return $this->price;
    }
}
$solution1 = ProductFactory::createProduct('solution1');
print $solution1->calculatePrice("02/25/1982", "male", 100000);
```

Comment: I love the `return; break;` combos. I always do that too. I type `case ...:` and `break;` and then anything in between. But I always have a `default: break;` too :)

Comment: default, yes will be adding that one :)
In terms of the ProductFactory - I think I've changed my thinking on this. Where Solution1Product would be the actual product - to be more of a type of product. Eg: BookProduct - book would have price, isbn, author, etc, etc.

Comment: Isn't it nice :) `$classname  = ucfirst( strtolower( $type ) )."Product";
if ( class_exists( $classname ) ) {
  return new $classname;
}`

Comment: you have a Procutfactory that creates Solutions? hmm... Personally I think you are looking at the problem the wrong way. I'll try and get an answer by this evening

Comment: *"return ...; break;"* simply doesn't make any sense. Adding a *"default:"* on the other hand would make sense.

Comment: Solution is actually a type of product, like a Bike or a Book.
Thanks, removed the break; after return

Comment: you have "return" in _construct. you shouldn't have return in constructor.

Answer (score 2):

### Flexible approach

1. First defining an ultimate abstraction of the factory
2. Implement it with product type - class mapping
3. Creating an entry point to register and use the factory

   ```
   interface IProductFactory {

       function createProduct($type);
   }

   class DefaultProductFactory implements IProductFactory {

       private $_mappings;

       public function __construct(array $mappings = array()) {
           $this->_mappings = $mappings;
       }

       public function addMappings(array $mappings) {
           $this->_mappings = array_merge($this->_mappings, $mappings);
       }

       public function createProduct($type) {
           if (!isset($this->_mappings[$type])) {
               throw new \Exception("Cannot create product of type " . $type);
           }

           $class = $this->_mappings[$type];

           //can be passed to a DI container to instantiate if needed

           return new $class();
       }
   }

   class ProductFactory {

       private static $_factory;

       public static function setCurrent(IProductFactory $factory) {
           $this->_factory = $factory;
       }

       public static function getCurrent() {
           return $this->_factory;
       }
   }

   ProductFactory::setCurrent(new DefaultProductFactory(array(
       "solution1" => "Solution1Product",
       "solution2" => "Solution2Product",
       "solution3" => "Solution3Product",
       "solution4" => "Solution4Product",
       "solution5" => "\\\\In\\\Some\\\\Other\\\\Namespace\\\\Solution5Product",
       )));

   $solution1 = ProductFactory::getCurrent()->createProduct('solution1');

   print $solution1->calculatePrice("02/25/1982", "male", 100000);
   ```